# Assign a specific sighandler to a signal

Tags: c

I have a question concerning signals in C. I want to assign some a specific sighandler to a signal.

My function is:

```
void searchOccurences(char **myString, char chr, int *occurences) {
   /* I perform some search actions here 
    * at the end of this function *occurrence will contain the 
    * the number occurrences of chr in myString*/
}
```

I want to assign this function to the SIGILL signal (i.e Illegal Instruction Signal), but I can't because the __sighandler_t handlers are of this kind of definition:

```
typedef void (*__sighandler_t) (int);
```

So How can I assign my function to this signal? What are the alternative solutions to what I want to do?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? How would it make any sense? How would the illegal instruction signal pass arguments to the function? Where would the output go? Why SIGILL? Who would send SIGILL?

Comment: It does have a sens, I want to send to my handler more information than the signum.
I'll raise manually the Illegal Instruction Signal. I could choose another signal to test, but I chose this one.
I won't verify the output, I just want to know how can I pass more parameters.

Comment: SIGILL is a signal that your operating system sends to your process when it executes an illegal instruction. You don't send data to signal handlers. The operating system does. The only information signal handlers get is that a signal occurred and in some cases, when you have special signal handlers, additional operating specific information (like addresses in case of SIGILL or SIGSEGV).

Comment: I can raise this signal using the "raise()" function.
I can understand from your answer that I can't pass manually other parameters to my handler ?

Comment: No you can't. That's not what signals are for.

Comment: If you want to call your function with your various parameters, just call it! Why use a signal if you intend to invoke the function manually? Don't try to abuse signals to do something they're not meant for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use SIGILL, that could mask a genuine error.  SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 are specifically for user defined signals.

You can't pass additional information, sorry, but there it is.  The best you can do is to store information in a global before raising a signal, but you must be certain of the sequence of events, or use some sort of synchronisation like a mutex.

By the way, are you aware that many C runtime library functions are not signal safe?

Comment: It's what I did , I've declared all my function's parameters as global variables. I was just wondering if I could do it this way, thanks.